# MongoDB java update a doument by a function with fields

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using mongodb, with java,
I have the following document structure :

```
{
     _id : ...
     total_items : 34
     avarage_cost : 54
}
```

now i have an item with its cost, and i want to update my collection so that the total will increase by 1 and the avarage cost will be right,
what would be the best way to do so?

I thought about doing something like this :

```
int cost = ... ;

BasicDBObject updatequery = new BasicDBObject();
updatequery.put("$inc", BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().add("total_items ", 1).get());    
updatequery.put("$function", "function(){this.avarage_cost = ((this.total_items-1)*this.avarage_cost + "+cost+"/) / this.total_items;}");
```

is this a good/working solution ? 
what would be the best way to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

For now you cannot run javascript code on update queries. There is an open issue on Jira.  Check issue [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-458).

You can solve this problem as follows :

1. Get current object.
2. If it is null calculate average_cost & total_items and insert into DB.
3. If it is not null, get current total_items & average_cost field.
4. Calculate new total_items & average_cost values.
5. Update those fields using [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/set/) query parameter.